# Save an image to a remote server

Tags: java

I was looking up the best way to save a file into a MySQL database, since I have a Java program that needs to save and retrieve several images. I first thought of setting up a table with a BLOB and using this code I found:

```
File image = new File("C:/image.jpg");
PrepareStatement psmnt = connection.prepareStatement
("insert into save_image(image) "+ "values(?)");

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(image);
psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, (InputStream)fis, (int)(image.length()));
/* executeUpdate() method execute specified sql query. Here this query 
insert data and image  */ 
int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

However, I was reading that using a MySQL database for images that have been serialized is not recommended for performance. I was told it was better to save pointers to directories within the server. How do you download and upload a file to a remote server? or do you recommend using the MySQL database instead?

Comment: Better to use AWS S3 to store image and save the URL of that image on MySQL database.

Comment: Never store an image to a database, just store the image to the filesystem and store the path to the image (for later retrieval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transfer the image to your server using sockets.
This would be a client/server communication so you need a sender and a receiver program.

**Client (Sender)**

```
public static void sendFileToServer() throws Exception {
        Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);

        // port has to be the same on client and server side
        int port = 1337; 

        //create a socket connection to the server
        Socket socket = new Socket("ipAdressOfTheServer", port);
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();

        // first write the length of the file so the receiver knows how much it has to read
        out.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(data.length).array());
        //write the actual file data
        out.write(data, 0, data.length);
        socket.close();
    }
```

**Server (Receiver)**

```
public static void receiveFile() throws Exception {
        //create a ServerSocket to listen for incoming connections
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1337);
        Socket senderSocket = server.accept();
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(senderSocket.getInputStream());
        //first read the length of the file
        int lengthOfFile = in.readInt();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[lengthOfFile];

        //then read the actual file bytes
        in.readFully(buffer);

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pathname");
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    }
```